# recompose pure or React.memo?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, recompose

I'm asking myself if the React.memo is exactly the same as recompose pure() ...

```
import { pure } from 'recompose';
export default pure(MyComp);
```

or

```
import React, { memo } from 'react';
export default memo(MyComp);
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent).

`React.memo is a higher order component. It’s similar to React.PureComponent but for function components instead of classes.`

So they are not **exactly** the same, but they serve the same purpose.

Comment: great answer! this is what I was looking for!

Comment: I think this is answering the difference between `React.memo` v.s. `React.PureComponent` instead of the difference between `React.memo` v.s. `decompose.pure`.